# Typesetting lots of short footnotes

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, typography

For a given book, I want to typeset lots of short footnotes on a page. The result is not looking very great.

Here is the basic rendering, using `scrbook` with standard footnotes:

[image: standard]

Using `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`:

[image: with footmisc]

Using `\usepackage[dblfootnote]`:

[image: with dblfootnote]

What other option could there be to properly typeset these footnotes?

Comment: I’ve never seen `footmisc` produce such ugly results; they seem to result from `frenchb`.  Using `\StandardFootnotes` improves the output considerably.

Comment: You are right! If you add this as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: I don’t think it’s much of an answer yet. Someone who understands the package code should figure out how `frenchb` and `footmisc` are interacting and whether they can be made to cooperate better without stepping on French typographic conventions. But maybe there’s reason to depart from the conventions here: all those numbers at the foot of the page, from the note numbers and the verse numbers, are hard to read, especially when the note numbers aren’t superscripted; old-style numbers and the `perpage` option of `footmisc` may ease the strain somewhat.

Comment: Yes. It does seem like `frenchb`'s implementation is buggy though, with numbers getting far too close to each other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{perpage}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}

\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]}
\makeatletter
  \let\@makefntext@orig\@makefntext
  \FootnoteSpecific{A}\def\@makefntext#1{%
      \noindent{\hbox{\textbf{\@thefnmark}\nolinebreak\ }}#1~\hss%
  }
\makeatother
```

This will give you all the footnotes (to be inserted via `footnoteA{...}`) as one continuous paragraph (first line not indented), bold footnotemarks and fixed spatia between the mark and the preceding and following text, respectively.
You can change the size of the whitespace by changing `\nolinebreak\ }}#1~` to another horizontal space of your liking.

HTH, Dario

Edit: Added `\MakePerPage` as per comment.

Comment: Thsi is not bad at all! I think it looks a bit nicer with a `\quad` though.

Comment: Glad it helps. You should indeed experiment with the size of the whitespace depending on your overall layout and page size.

Comment: Actually, is there a reason why this won't reset the footnote counter for every page, like it seems to be the default for `bigfoot`?

Comment: The counter running though is standard behaviour. If you want to have it reset every page, you can use the package perpage:
`\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnoteA}`
I've updated my answer to include it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm testing this, and seeing edge effects with `perpage`, where the numbers are reset at the bottom of pages. It seems running LaTeX thrice fixes this though.